# Highcharts Tooltip cropping

Tags: highcharts

I am using high charts but am experiencing an issue with larger tooltip cropping off at the outer elements of the SVG, as per the image below.

[image]

The option `useHTML` is set to true for the tooltip and xAxis, as I am applying some custom CSS these elements.

Is there a way to have the tooltip not to crop?

My highcharts code looks like this:

```
        return {
        chart: {
            renderTo: this._chartContainer,
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },
        title: {
            text: this._getTitle(values)
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: values.rows.labels[0],
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<span class="xAxisTruncate" title="' + this.value + '">'+ this.value +'</span>';
                },
                useHTML: true
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            max: this._getMax(),
            min: this._getMin(),
            gridLineWidth: 2,
            opposite: true,
            tickInterval: 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '%b %y'
            },
            title: {
                text: yAxisTitleText
            },
            endOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderColor: 'transparent',
                borderRadius: 5,
                groupPadding: 0.05
            },
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                animation: false,
                colorByPoint: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: columnRangeSeries,
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function(){
                return this.point.toolTip;
            }
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure, that similar topic exists on stack, however I can't find it. In general it is possible to achieve that using HTML tooltip, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7wVDV/147/

CSS:

```
.highcharts-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.MyChartTooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 108, 169);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome, didn't know highcharts still use a svg shape as tooltip's background even if `useHTML` is `ture` before reading your code, thanks :)