# Force Highcharts to display tooltip outside of div/container

Tags: css, highcharts, tooltip

[Highcharts]

Hello, is there a way to display the tooltip outside the  tags? Like to make it "float" outside the container so that it doesn't get cutoff like below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Tooltip is cutoff]

Here's an example jsFiddle you can use to reproduce the issue. (Try hovering over the boxplot)

http://jsfiddle.net/af3g18mo/ `Code`

Comment: You can use solution from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your fiddle i can figure out the Problem:

If you go up one cascade in your stylesheet you can see that your paths and stuff is within a  tag. 
The tag has the fix height of 65px and no overflow attributes - but one path before there is the `overflow:hidden`. This is why the highchart tooltips and everything is just cut off.

You can change your height dynamically to for example 40% what doesn't really fix the problem if you have longer contents in your tooltip. but you can give a `"overflow:visible;"` to your `<svg>` and overwrite the `"overflow:hidden"` in your `".highcharts-container"` with visible - so all the contents like your tooltips that have more than 65 px height are displayed.

You can see the solution here: 
be careful changing these things, but in your example i couldn't see any bad reactions to this change. In case you have to give your css the whole path to not change it globally.

http://jsfiddle.net/af3g18mo/2/

So the concrete fixing for your css could be:

```
svg{
    overflow:visible;
}
.highcharts-container{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: check out about the overflow attribute here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Hello, Thanks for helping. I tried that but it didn't work. Here's an example of the code I modified using the official Highcharts example. (I reduced the height on purpose) 

http://jsfiddle.net/af3g18mo/ 

try hovering over the boxplot, you can see the tooltip being cutoff.

Comment: here the easiest example of the overflow stuff. 
http://jsfiddle.net/6zkxadxp/
you sometimes just have to look one part in your path above to find the given attributes that avoid your changes =) good luck hope this helps you.