# Highcharts column tooltip - always on top + fit the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, tooltip

I have a highchart graph with tooltips. This is how I want to render tooltips every time.

[image: good case]

When the tootlip doesn't fit the svg container, highcharts swaps the position of tooltip like this.

[image: bad case]

I know how to fix this but when I do this.

```
positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
    return {
        x: point.plotX,
        y: point.plotY - boxHeight
    };
},
```

Tooltip is correctly always on top, but overflows to the right(image_1). I would like to have the tooltip always on top + fit the container from the sides. (image_2)

[image]

[image]

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Thanks (http://jsfiddle.net/4xomw3aj/)

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/4xomw3aj/ thanks

Comment: You can use solution form this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping to avoid cropping.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xomw3aj/2/

Comment: And could you point me what is wrong?

Comment: Tooltip still overflows on right see http://i.imgur.com/BxyyJcV.png

Comment: The tooltip is above chart and edge, but seems that your container cuts tooltip. I was not able to replicate this issue by: http://jsfiddle.net/4xomw3aj/ can you update that code?

Comment: I just uncommented 'fix' in positioner - http://jsfiddle.net/4xomw3aj/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found out how to 'not swap'. In Tooltip.getPosition()

```
firstDimension = function (dim, outerSize, innerSize, point) {
    ret[dim] = point - distance - innerSize;
},
```

Comment: Could you provide the resulting callback function? Thank you.

Comment: @Vladimir Volek could you please provide an example on how to use and where to use this function. Thank you.