# Dynamic position of tooltip in highcharts column charts

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts

I have an issue with tooltip in Highcharts column charts. When series fill my chart, the tooltip is under the serie. But he is cut by then end of div, as you can see here :
[image: Bug tooltip]
What should I do to make my tooltip not cut ?

If the first proposal is not possible, how can I place it over chart instead of under ?
By the way I tried it with positioner but can't not find a way to get X position hovered.

Question is probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627), but the solution is different.

Edit : explain unicity of my question

Comment: Dupliate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to get X position of pointer.
According to highcharts Doc, positioner function receives 3 parameters : labelWidth, labelHeight, point.
Then use point.plotX in function.

Comment: an example to use positioner is below

  positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {         
           var tooltipX, tooltipY;
              if (point.plotX + labelWidth > this.chart.plotWidth) {
                  tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft - labelWidth - 40;
              } else {
                  tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft + 40;
              }
              tooltipY = point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - 20;
              return {
                  x: tooltipX,
                  y: tooltipY
              };       
         }

Comment: I'm having trouble using positioner with the "column" chart type? Anyone else have this issue?