# How to set the position of the first and last child of the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

The toolTip will be cropped as below if the data is very small on ends of the charts as in the below picture. Please suggest a solution for this

[image]

Comment: You can use solution like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 different solutions. First, count if the tooltip need to show on right or left:

```
positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
    var tooltipX, tooltipY;
    if (point.plotX + labelWidth > chart.plotWidth) {
        tooltipX = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - labelWidth - 20;
    } else {
        tooltipX = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 20;
    }
    tooltipY = point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 20;
    return {
        x: tooltipX,
        y: tooltipY
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/eSfy8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=eSfy8

Or with a fixed position of the tooltip:

```
positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
    var tooltipX, tooltipY;
    if (point.plotX + chart.plotLeft < labelWidth && point.plotY + labelHeight > chart.plotHeight) {
        tooltipX = chart.plotLeft;
        tooltipY = chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 2 * labelHeight - 10;
    } else {
        tooltipX = chart.plotLeft;
        tooltipY = chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - labelHeight;
    }
    return {
        x: tooltipX,
        y: tooltipY
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/8cJD7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=8cJD7

With your chart type the tooltip is the same, you only need to take care if 'chart' is defined (usually is).

Hope it helps!