# Highchart tooltip variable width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using following css code for highStock tooltip:

```
.highcharts-tooltip > span {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFAE19;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

But now in one of my chart a series name is too long to fit in the above width. If I increase the width in css then it will disturb the layout for rest of the charts.

Please sugest how I can handle this situation ?

Comment: You can use the solution with HTML tooltip, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use CSS at all if you're using the Highcharts API.  Highcharts tooltips have attributes that can be used to style your tooltip as desired, and the `style` attribute can be used for any remaining CSS styling necessary.

See Highcharts' [tooltip documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) for more information