# HighChart: Navigator Handles are on top of tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am actually facing this situation for my chart

[image]

I guess is some kind of Z-Index of issue. But On the [HighChart reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.handles) there is no option to fix z-index.

I tried with:

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

This is the code for the `Formatter` function.

```
    formatter: function () {
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:'/ajax/toolTips/RawMaterialChartTt.aspx',
            async:false,
            data: {date:Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y',this.x), data:paramData}, //paramData is an array with series name and color
            dataType : "html",
            success: function(data) {
                result = $(data).find('#showresults').html();
            },
            error: function(errorThrown) { 
                console.log(errorThrown.responseText);
            } 
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can use the solution from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Comment: If you don't have the "useHTML: true" option set in your tooltips then you need to use that in order for CSS rules to take effect.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes `useHTML` is `True`

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same issue. I had fixed this issue by adding the CSS for the highcharts-tooltip.

```
highcharts-tooltip 
{
 background-color:White;
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWvhH.png]