# How to show tooltip properly for highchairs when height is small?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I use highchairs in grid table (ui-grid) and I have cell height `20px`

How  to show tooltip **properly**?

This is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j57x52ys/)

[image]

---

My code:

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({ // This is for all plots, change Date axis to local timezone
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      width:160,
      height:20,
      renderTo: 'container',
      margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      //max: 1,
      maxPadding: 0,
      minPadding: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      endOnTick: false,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {   
                                    //enabled: false,
                                    formatter: function () {
                                       return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' +  this.point.y
                                   } ,
                                   //positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                                   //     return {x:point.plotX,y:point.plotY-20};
                                   // }
                               },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      //pointHeight:20,
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            states:{
                              hover:false
                            },
        //enableMouseTracking: false,
        lineWidth: 1,
        shadow: false,
        states: {
          hover: {
            lineWidth: 1
          }
        },
        animation: false
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        "name": "Open",
        "nameStr": "Open",
        "id": "open",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 1,
            "color": "#c44a53"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "In Progress",
        "nameStr": "In Progress",
        "id": "in progress",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 0,
            "color": "#71dedf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Almost Done",
        "nameStr": "Almost Done",
        "id": "almost done",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 0,
            "color": "#5dcfd0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Done",
        "nameStr": "Done",
        "id": "done",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 0,
            "color": "#47b9c7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Closed",
        "nameStr": "Closed",
        "id": "closed",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 0,
            "color": "#a7b75b"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "On Hold",
        "nameStr": "On Hold",
        "id": "on hold",
        "data": [
          {
            "extras": {},
            "y": 0,
            "color": "#eaeaea"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  });
});
```

Comment: You can style the tooltip box and text to make it fit. But, you are essentially doing a sparkline type chart. Could you use datalabel instead to show value?

Comment: You can use a workaround with customised tooltip like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680627/highcharts-tooltip-cropping

Answer (score 1):

You can style the tooltip text elements and other items to make them smaller. At what point this becomes unreadable is up to your user testing. Something like:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.point.y
  },
  style: {
    "color": "#333333",
    "cursor": "default",
    "fontSize": "10px", //default is 12px
    "padding": "1px", //default is 8px
    "pointerEvents": "none",
    "whiteSpace": "nowrap"
  }
},
```

Here I have set the `padding` to 1px and the `fontSize` to 10px.